# Detecting objects in unity 3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I got an object named pacman, I want to know if there's another objects(coockies) at his right and left.
For example, my pacman position is (-55,5,-55) and I want to know if there's a cookie at (-45,5,-55), 10 units at his right.
I used Physics.OverlapSphere but it gave me all the cookies around pacman and I want to check separately right and then left.

Comment: Why don't you create the overlap sphere 10 units at his right or left?

Comment: Because it checks all objects around a radius.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way.

```
public void Detect(GameObject pacman, float radius) {

        Vector3 pacmanPosition = pacman.transform.position;

        var hitColliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(pacmanPosition, radius);

        for (var i = 0; i < hitColliders.Length; i++) {
            if(hitColliders[i].gameObject.transform.position.x == (pacmanPosition.x-10)){
                //TODO
            }
            else if(hitColliders[i].gameObject.transform.position.x == (pacmanPosition.x+10)){
                //TODO
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should travel all `Collider` from the return of `Physics.OverlapSphere`, and check `collider.transform.position`